# Get category related only to the current single-post

Tags: wordpress, foreach, custom-post-type, posts, related-posts

I'd like to ask for help. I don't know if its possible.

I have a "single-teams.php" custom post type, there I'm using a foreach get_posts loop and I would like to showcase only the related news(posts) category. So if I have "XYZ" single-teams post I would like to showcase posts only with "XYZ" category. If have "XZY" single-teams post I want it to showcase posts only with the "XZY" category.

```
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 4,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'category__in'     => array(2),
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
);
$news = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $news as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post ); 
    $image = get_field('image', $post->ID);
    $image = $image['sizes']['large'];
        $catNames = array();
        foreach( (get_the_category()) as $category) {
            $catNames[] = $category->cat_name;
        }
```

I have this code so far. But it showcases the "XZY" category posts on the "XYZ" single post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me how post-types `teams` and `post` are related.
What do you mean by

> "XYZ" category

The category whose slug is "xyz"? The category whose name is "XYZ"?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your clarifications. So you want that, if you are on the "XYZ" team page, the posts assigned to the category whose name is "XYX" are shown? Try using the `tax_query` argument in the custom query:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 4,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => get_the_title()
        )
    ),
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
);
$news = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $news as $post ) : 
    setup_postdata( $post ); 
    $image = get_field('image', $post->ID);
    $image = $image['sizes']['large'];
        $catNames = array();
        foreach( (get_the_category()) as $category) {
            $catNames[] = $category->cat_name;
        }
endforeach;
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for trying to help!
So i have a custom post type called "Teams" under that I create different teams with different team names. 
So if I have XYZ team, I'd like to display wordpress posts(news) only with "XYZ" added  post category. But right now, "XYZ" post category appears on the "XZY" team as well.

Comment: And yes XYZ team display posts only with "xyz" category slug.
XZY team display posts only with "xzy" category slug.
But XYZ team shouldn't display post with "xzy" category slug.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working! Would it possible to showcase the slug name instead of the category name/title?

Comment: Based on your code snippet, I can't see where you are showing the category names on the front end. I can assume that somehow the $catNames variable is involved. So you can try writing
$catNames[] = $category->slug;
instead of
$catNames[] = $category->cat_name;

EDIT: Glad you got it sorted out.